# The fgets function doesnt save the first letter in the string

Tags: c

I've wrote a program that gets from the user a number, and then gets from the user a name for every number...
for example if the user entered the number 10, it'd take 10 names and put it in an array of structs...
Everything is working great, except that when I print the names, it skip'd the first letter...
like if I put in the name "Amit", it printed "mit"... , also, the last string I've entered didnt save at all..
Here is what I wrote :

```
const number_candidates; // Getting the number of candidates
#define MAX 256
#define min_candidate 10
#define max_candidate 60000

typedef struct candidate // Getting details for each candidate
{
    char name[MAX];
    int sing_grade;
    int per_grade;
    int cam_grade;
    int sharmanti_grade;
}candidate;

void get_details_candidates(candidate candidate[MAX])
{
 int i = 0;
 printf ("\n");
 for (i = 0 ; i < number_candidates ; i++)
 {
     printf ("Please enter the %d name: ", i + 1);
     fgets (candidate[i].name, MAX, stdin);
     getchar();
 }
}
```

Here is the printing:

```
    for (i = 0 ; i < number_candidates ; i++)     
{
    printf ("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you have that `getchar()` after the `fgets()`?

Comment: Becuase in the first time the loop starts, it doesnt get the first name...

Comment: That's odd. I don't know why your first string isn't being read but that `getchar()` call is definitely eating the first character of the following input line. [Example code here](http://ideone.com/k1Gmr)

Comment: ur right...
so now my only problem is the first fgets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getchar()` after the `fgets()` is eating the first letter of the following line.

Your problem reading the first name may be caused by a stray newline in the input stream. To flush `stdin` before your input loop you can use something like this:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
/* discard the character */;
```

I think `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour so **don't do that**.

Answer (score 3):

Why do have the getchar() after the fgets()? I think that is your culprit.

Comment: When I take down the getchar(); from the fgets, it works propely, with the 10th word and the first letter in every name,
but at the first time it asks for a name, it doesnt get a name from the user, and go stright for the second name....